# How do I get the original value in handlebars register helpers?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have moved into latest Ember version 1.9.1 and Handlebars version 2.0.0. In this, I am getting an error like "Usage of Ember.Handlebars.get is deprecated, use a Component or Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper instead."

I have a code like this,

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (temp_v1, operator, temp_v2, options) { // No I18N

    var v1,v2;
    v1 = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, temp_v1, options);
    v2 = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, temp_v2, options);

        if( v1 == undefined ){
            v1 = temp_v1;
        }
        if( v2 == undefined ){
            v2 = temp_v2;
        }


        switch (operator) {
          case '==':
            return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
          case '!=':
            return (v1 != v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
          default:
            return options.inverse(this);
        }
 });
```

Here, I need to check the given string value is equal or not. If I remove the "Handlebars" in Ember.Handlebars.get(this, temp_v1, options), that deprecation error will be gone. But I couldn't get the original value of temp_v1.

JSBIN LINK: [JSBIN LINK](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/duhicecuco/1/)

Comment: A little suggestion: don't use any logical operation in handlebars. It prevents you writing tests.

Comment: What is your suggestion to get rid of the ifs? Where should be the logic?

Answer (score 1):

With minimum modifications to the code posted, a possible solution could be along the lines of setting a properly modified `itemController` to the `{{each}}` helper and then retrieve the targeted property from this controller.

This approach strongly couples the `itemController` structure (i.e. the `item` property and `toString` function) to the hbs template structure (i.e. the `item` property defined within the `each` helper), which is not that bad as long as the helper remains independent and reusable.

Example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/geqezicaki/1/edit?html,js

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model itemController="test"}}
    {{#ifCond item '==' red}}
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/ifCond}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (temp_v1, operator, temp_v2, options) { // No I18N

        var v1,v2;
        //v1 = Ember.get(this, temp_v1, options);
        //v2 = Ember.get(this, temp_v2, options);
  v1 = options.data.view.get("controller").get(temp_v1);
  v2 = options.data.view.get("controller").get(temp_v2);

            if( v1 === undefined ){
                v1 = temp_v1;
            }
            if( v2 === undefined ){
                v2 = temp_v2;
            }


            switch (operator) {
              case '==':
                return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
              case '!=':
                return (v1 != v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
              default:
                return options.inverse(this);
            }
     });


App.TestController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  item:Em.computed.alias("model"),
  toString:function(){return this.get("item");}
});
```